# Removing trailing Spaces from Long Datatype PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, trim, spaces, typeconverter

I have a Long with a couple of sentences in it, at the end there is a huge amount of blank spaces that need removed.
The problem is that the I have wrote a function to convert this long to a Varchar2 and trim the spaces but this has not worked.

I have used, RTRIM, TRIM TRAILING, TRIM and even tried replace " " with "" (but that just removed all spaces even between words.

Example:

```
SELECT TRIM(comment)
FROM p_comments
WHERE p_domain = 'SIGNATURE'
AND p_code = c_p_code;
```

This did not work as it cannot perform the trim on a "LONG".

```
SELECT RTRIM(f_get_varchar(get_p_code('JOHN'))) FROM dual
```

Did not work and just returned the same result.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Send the code of f_get_varchar function and exact sample of not working case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the answer. I used a regular expression.

```
SELECT regexp_substr(cis.acs_reports.f_get_varchar(:p_pfo_code), '.+[^space::]') pfo_comment
```

FROM dual